# How to know the SOLR index size and query hits?

Tags: solr

We have the `SOLR 8.8.2` version and hosted in `Azure Paas`.

We would like to get the index size and how many queries hits on particular index in month.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re using `Solr 8.2` or newer there’s a built-in index analysis tool that
gives you a better understanding of what kind of data in your index occupies
the most disk space, so that you can tweak your schema accordingly:

The `COLSTATUS` command provides a detailed description of the collection status, including low-level index information about segments and field data.

This command also checks the compliance of Lucene index field types with the current Solr collection schema and indicates the names of non-compliant fields, i.e., Lucene fields with field types incompatible (or different) from the corresponding Solr field types declared in the current schema. Such incompatibilities may result from incompatible schema changes or after migration of data to a different major Solr release.

`/admin/collections?action=COLSTATUS&collection=coll&coreInfo=true&segments=true&fieldInfo=true&sizeInfo=true`

**Examples using COLSTATUS**

Input: `http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=COLSTATUS&collection=gettingstarted&fieldInfo=true&sizeInfo=true`

Output

```
{
    "responseHeader": {
        "status": 0,
        "QTime": 50
    },
    "gettingstarted": {
        "stateFormat": 2,
        "znodeVersion": 16,
        "properties": {
            "autoAddReplicas": "false",
            "maxShardsPerNode": "-1",
            "nrtReplicas": "2",
            "pullReplicas": "0",
            "replicationFactor": "2",
            "router": {
                "name": "compositeId"
            },
            "tlogReplicas": "0"
        },
        "activeShards": 2,
        "inactiveShards": 0,
        "schemaNonCompliant": [
            "(NONE)"
        ],
        "shards": {
            "shard1": {
                "state": "active",
                "range": "80000000-ffffffff",
                "replicas": {
                    "total": 2,
                    "active": 2,
                    "down": 0,
                    "recovering": 0,
                    "recovery_failed": 0
                },
                "leader": {
                    "coreNode": "core_node4",
                    "core": "gettingstarted_shard1_replica_n1",
                    "base_url": "http://192.168.0.80:8983/solr",
                    "node_name": "192.168.0.80:8983_solr",
                    "state": "active",
                    "type": "NRT",
                    "force_set_state": "false",
                    "leader": "true",
                    "segInfos": {
                        "info": {
                            "minSegmentLuceneVersion": "9.0.0",
                            "commitLuceneVersion": "9.0.0",
                            "numSegments": 40,
                            "segmentsFileName": "segments_w",
                            "totalMaxDoc": 686953,
                            "userData": {
                                "commitCommandVer": "1627350608019193856",
                                "commitTimeMSec": "1551962478819"
                            }
                        },
                        "fieldInfoLegend": [
                            "I - Indexed",
                            "D - DocValues",
                            "xxx - DocValues type",
                            "V - TermVector Stored",
                            "O - Omit Norms",
                            "F - Omit Term Frequencies & Positions",
                            "P - Omit Positions",
                            "H - Store Offsets with Positions",
                            "p - field has payloads",
                            "s - field uses soft deletes",
                            ":x:x:x - point data dim : index dim : num bytes"
                        ],
                        "segments": {
                            "_i": {
                                "name": "_i",
                                "delCount": 738,
                                "softDelCount": 0,
                                "hasFieldUpdates": false,
                                "sizeInBytes": 109398213,
                                "size": 70958,
                                "age": "2019-03-07T12:34:24.761Z",
                                "source": "merge",
                                "version": "9.0.0",
                                "createdVersionMajor": 9,
                                "minVersion": "9.0.0",
                                "diagnostics": {
                                    "os": "Mac OS X",
                                    "java.vendor": "Oracle Corporation",
                                    "java.version": "1.8.0_191",
                                    "java.vm.version": "25.191-b12",
                                    "lucene.version": "9.0.0",
                                    "mergeMaxNumSegments": "-1",
                                    "os.arch": "x86_64",
                                    "java.runtime.version": "1.8.0_191-b12",
                                    "source": "merge",
                                    "mergeFactor": "10",
                                    "os.version": "10.14.3",
                                    "timestamp": "1551962064761"
                                },
                                "attributes": {
                                    "Lucene50StoredFieldsFormat.mode": "BEST_SPEED"
                                },
                                "largestFiles": {
                                    "_i.fdt": "42.5 MB",
                                    "_i_Lucene80_0.dvd": "35.3 MB",
                                    "_i_Lucene50_0.pos": "11.1 MB",
                                    "_i_Lucene50_0.doc": "10 MB",
                                    "_i_Lucene50_0.tim": "4.3 MB"
                                },
                                "ramBytesUsed": {
                                    "total": 49153,
                                    "postings [PerFieldPostings(segment=_i formats=1)]": {
                                        "total": 31023,
                                "fields": {
                                    "dc": {
                                        "flags": "I-----------",
                                        "schemaType": "text_general"
                                    },
                                    "dc_str": {
                                        "flags": "-Dsrs-------",
                                        "schemaType": "strings"
                                    },
                                    "dc.title": {
                                        "flags": "I-----------",
                                        "docCount": 70958,
                                        "sumDocFreq": 646756,
                                        "sumTotalTermFreq": 671817,
                                        "schemaType": "text_general"
                                    },
                                    "dc.date": {
                                        "flags": "-Dsrn-------:1:1:8",
                                        "schemaType": "pdates"
                                    }
                                  }}}}}}}}}}}
```

Reference: https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_2/collection-management.html#colstatus

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you your response. It seems this was for solr cloud. We are not running solr in cloud mode and getting the below message.

"Solr instance is not running in SolrCloud mode."